# Removing combinations from a permutation

Tags: java, arrays, string, permutation

I am fairly new to Java and programming and have been trying to find a way to accomplish what I want to do for a while now. I want to remove some combinations from this string array permutation, such as (1,2,3,4,5,6) , or (1,2,3,4,5,7). I have tried filtering or .remove , but it seems they do not work with string arrays. Basically I would like to be able to filter the results removing unwanted combinations. Here is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Permutations {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] arraylist = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"};

    combinations2(arraylist, 6, 0, new String[6]);
  }

  static void combinations2(String[] arraylist, int len, int startPosition, String[] result) {

    if (len == 0) {

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
      return;
    }
    for (int i = startPosition; i <= arraylist.length - len; i++) {
      result[result.length - len] = arraylist[i];
      combinations2(arraylist, len - 1, i + 1, result);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "I have tried filtering or .remove" Please show this in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically need to use arrays I would suggest switching to a standard collection. They are easy to use and you won't need to pass indices around as you can use sub-lists. The code below uses a standard `contains` method to filter out unwanted combinations.

```
public class Combos {
    private static final List<List<String>> FILTER = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
        Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "7"));

    static void combos(List<String> input, List<String> result) {
        if (result.size() == 6) {
            if (!FILTER.contains(result))
                System.out.println(result);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
                result.add(input.get(i));
                combos(input.subList(i + 1, input.size()), result);
                result.remove(input.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        combos(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 13)
                .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()), 
                new ArrayList<>());
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try to use your code it says Arrays cannot be resolved, and List cannot be resolved to a type. It is not important if I use permutations, sets, or lists. I just want to achieve the result of creating combinations of a 6 element length and filtering out certian combinations such as 2,3,4,5,6,7 and 1,3,4,5,6,8.

Comment: You need to add import statements to get access to the classes.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. One thing I noticed is that in your `main` method, you call your `combinations2` method with the line, `combinations2(arraylist, 6, 0, new String[6]);`. I was wondering why you might store your *result* in a `new String[]` that looses the scope right after you call it (essentially you are not storing the parsed array here - I'd suggest making it stored to another array in order to use it purposefully, you can see the following code snippet for example.).

As per answering the question, I'd looking into the [System.arrayCopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) method, and use it like this:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arraylist = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13" };
        System.out.println("arraylist: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(arraylist));
        String[] result= new String[arraylist.length - 6];
        System.arraycopy(arraylist, 6, result, 0, arraylist.length - 6);
        System.out.println("result: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(result));
    } 
}
```

Output;

```
arraylist: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
result: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Also, as of 1.5 and later there is [Arrays.copyOfRange(Object[] src, int from, int to)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

However, in the case you're not removing sequentially, this would become rather tedious/repetitive making multiple System.arraycopy() calls (*e.g. in your second case of (1,2,3,4,5,7) *).

Comment: What you have suggested works, but it removes the 6 element format. I want to keep the format I have, but remove specific combinations that I do not wish to keep. I am not sure how to achieve that from what you have shown me here.

Comment: Could you explain more, or edit in a before/after example to your original post? Specific combinations may be better dealt with Collections as opposed to System.arraycopy.